# show that the parametrization is an **arc length parametrization** if and only if $ \ \vec v \ $ is a unit vector

Tags: calculus

Find the arc length formula $ \ s(t)=\int_0^t || r'(t) || dt \ $ of the line with parametric equation $ \ r(t)=\vec w(t)+t \vec v(t) \ $.

Hence show that the parametrization is an **arc length parametrization** if and only if $ \ \vec v \ $ is a unit vector ie., $ \ || \vec v(t) ||=1 \ $.

**Answer:**

we say that $ \ r(t) \ $ is parametrized by arc length if $ \ s(t)=\int_{0}^{t} || r'(u) || du=t-0=t \ $

Suppose $ \ r(t) \ $ is parametrize by its arc length , then

$ s(t)=\int_0^t ||r'(u) || du =t \ $

Taking derivative of both sides , we get

$ v(t)=1 \ $

Taking norm , we get

$ || v(t)||=1  \ $

Conversely , I can not do it.

Help me out

Comment: I have a question regarding your argument that $|v|=1$. Since $r'=w'+tv'+v$ how do you obtain $|v|=1$ by just knowing $|r'|=1$? $w$ might be anything and without assumptions on it i doubt you can control $r'$ just by $v$.